# Using strtok and trying to store their values into an array

Tags: c, arrays, strtok

I'm pretty new to C and I've been trying something but it doesn't seem to really work:
I have an array `char *initialParts;` and I'm allocating space according to the input of a user, but I don't think that's really important.
I've also got a counter `initialPartsCounter = 0;` that I use as an index so that at each index of the memory allocated I store in it a letter.
So far I've got this:

```
            char *initialParts;
            const char comma[3] = ",";
            int initialPartsCounter = 0;
            initialParts = (char*)malloc((int)numInitialParts * sizeof(char));
            char *token;
            token = strtok(fileLine, comma);

            while (token != NULL) {
                strcpy(&initialParts[initialPartsCounter], token);
                initialPartsCounter++;
                token = strtok(NULL, comma);
            }

            for (int l = 0 ; l < (int)numInitialParts; l++)
            {
                printf("%c", initialParts[l]);
            }
```

where numInitialParts is the number entered by the user and fileLine is a line read in a file.
In the following example, `numInitialParts = 4`, `and fileLine = 'q,d,c,k'`
In my for loop, the output printed is weird: `qdck☐☐☐☐` (I couldn't copy the characters after k because it wasn't doing anything when I pasted it but it somethings similar, check the pic to see how it looks).

[image]

EDIT: My ideal output would be:

```
qdck
```

If anyone has an idea to solve this, I'll be happy hear it. Thanks!

Comment: "*the output printed is weird*" which output do you expect?

Comment: Is `initialParts` a `char*` ? Please, post a complete example. Also: how is `filename` defined?

Comment: You read `initialPartsCounter` tokens but print `numInitialParts` characters.

Comment: "store their values into an array" Of strings or characters? It sort of looks like you're trying to remove the delimiters from the input string. Please add to your post two things: (a) sample string and (b) what you want the output to look like. This is why it's often best to write your tests first.

Comment: What do you want the console to show if fileLine is `x,k,c,d,,xk,xkc,xkcd`. Such an example will expose more edges.

Comment: Sorry I added more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you print

```
printf("%c", initialParts[l]);
```

I can guess that initialParts is defined as a `char *` and then dynamically allocated.

`strtok` is normal used to obtain tokens of various lengths. Even though you might be sure than the original comma-separated strings are composed by just a character, when you perform

```
strcpy(&initialParts[initialPartsCounter], token);
```

You are copying to the char array **at least** two characters: the character of the token (for example 'q') and the string terminator `'\0'` (a string is just a zero terminated char array, and all string manipulation funtions rely on it).

Just do

```
initialParts[initialPartsCounter] = *token;
```

Indeed it wasn't the main mistake. In fact, even though it shows some misunderstanding of how `strtok` works, it will work until there's enough room in `initialParts` array to store the current character and the string terminator.

The other mistake is that, though you get only `initialPartsCounter` characters from `strtok` parsing  but you print all the characters of the array (`numInitialParts`). Those at the end will be meaningless, so correcting it the code will work as expected.

The following example embeds your code in a simple main function (I manually defined the input `char fileLine[] = "q,d,c,k"):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char *initialParts, *token;
  char fileLine[] = "q,d,c,k";
  const char comma[3] = ",";
  int initialPartsCounter = 0, numInitialParts = 20;
  initialParts = (char*)malloc((int)numInitialParts * sizeof(char));

  token = strtok(fileLine, comma);

  while (token != NULL)
  {
    //strcpy(&initialParts[initialPartsCounter], token);
    initialParts[initialPartsCounter] = *token; //Use this only if tokens are only one char long
    initialPartsCounter++;
    token = strtok(NULL, comma);
  }

  for (int l = 0 ; l < initialPartsCounter; l++)
  {
    printf("%c", initialParts[l]);
  }
  printf("*end\n");

  free(initialParts);

  return 0;
}
```

I printed also a *closing string* to show how there's not any trailing unexpected character. The output is

```
qdck*end
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work, I still get the same output.

Comment: Have you also changed your for loop from `for (int l = 0 ; l < (int)numInitialParts; l++)` to `for (int l = 0 ; l < (int)InitialPartsCounter; l++)`?

Comment: @MM1. I'm afk. Later I'll sort it out

Comment: @MM1 I tried it, and I confirm it works. If in your full implementation it doesn't work it probably means that the code you attached is not complete. I'll edit my answer with a complete main application demonstrating its behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
initialParts = (char*)malloc((int)numInitialParts * sizeof(char));
```

You should use double pointer or 2D array to store the `token` (because it is character sequence (the string) not the character). If you do not know how many parts before, you can use `realloc` each time you increase the `numInitialParts`

For example:

```
char **initialParts = malloc(sizeof(char*));

// check initialParts here

token = strtok(fileLine, comma);

while (token != NULL) {
    initialParts[initialPartsCounter] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);
    // check initialParts[initialPartsCounter] here
    strcpy(initialParts[initialPartsCounter], token);
    initialPartsCounter++;
    initialParts = realloc((initialPartsCounter+1)*sizeof(char));
    // check initialParts here
    token = strtok(NULL, comma);
 }
```